# Can I query firestore with a wildcard as admin in a cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

```
exports.updateRelatedCards = functions.firestore
  .document('topic/{newTopic}')
  .onWrite((snap, context) => {
    const newTopic = snap.data();

    // search for the recieved title in a 'relatedCards' subcollection
    return firestore
      .collection(`card/{anyCard}/relatedCards`)
      .where('title', '==', newTopic.title)
      .get()
      .then(coll => {
        const list = coll.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
        return list ? list : 'nolist';
      })
      .then(list => console.log('list', list))
      .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
  });
```

is it possible to use `.where()` on a firestore query that has a wildcard in a cloud function?

Despite the data existing, I keep getting an empty array, I don't understand if I am doing something wring or if it it just not possible. There doesn't seem to be any mention of querying on the admin firestore docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't query Firestore with a wildcard in any context or with any SDK.  This is invalid:

```
firestore.collection(`card/{anyCard}/relatedCards`)
```

If you're going to reference a document or collection, you need to provide the real, actual path to it.  You can't wildcard any part of the path.

If you try a more simple query for a known collection and document, it will work just fine.

Comment: thanks @doug Any update on the a `collection group query` feature?

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  It's not possible to query across collections, and it's not likely to be supported, as far as I understand.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just saw a video that says you might be supporting the ability to search across subcollections https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IdKEhWAV-kE so I was wondering if there was any progress on that. Shame it's not in the works.

Comment: What specifically was said about that?

Comment: "...it's something the team is looking into, they'd really like to support it..." 2:23

Comment: I don't know about that.  There are typically no promises or timelines for Google developer products.

Comment: Firestore now supports querying across collections with Collection Group queries. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Comment: @RayLi While that is true, there's not enough information in this question to know if a collection group query is sufficient for this.  A collection group query will query *all* collections of a given name both top- and mid-level collections. It's not clear if that's going to work in this specific situation.